# How do I make vertices straight?

Tags: mesh, vertices, shortcut

As you can see the vertices are crooked and at an awkward 3D angle, how do I straighten them regardless what position each vertices are at? Is there a shortcut?[image]

Comment: you could use the knife tool

Answer (score 4):

I first thought it was a "flat" mesh but it looks actually 3D, so in that case the knife tool, as suggested by Chris, is probably the best solution: Use <kbd>K</kbd> to activate, then <kbd>Z</kbd> to cut through. You can also try <kbd>J</kbd> to join the vertices.

If it was a flat mesh, you have an addon called ***[EdgeFlow](https://github.com/BenjaminSauder/EdgeFlow/releases)*** made by Benjamin Sauder that allows you to align edges (I don't know why align vertices/edges is not a default tool in Blender). Once installed, select the edges and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> (or header menu > *Edge*) > *Set Linear*:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I realize that your mesh is actually not flat, to cut through it with the knife, you need to press the Z key

Comment: I tried using the Z key but it keeps bringing up the shading menu.

Comment: I meant Z just after K  ;)